# How do I show specified content for each user? Larvel 6

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering on how to assign a role to user and personalize the database queries for the roles or users.

I am trying show different data for each user based on their roles while logging in.

Example

I have a 3 table, - *`User,User Details,Status`*

**User**

```
 id         name 

 1          admin   
 2          manager
 3          employee
 4          user1
 5          user2
 ....
```

**State**

```
 id         status_name 

 1          status1   
 2          satus2
 3          status3
 ....
```

**User Details**

```
 id         status_id 

 4          3   
 5          2
 6          2
 7          1
 8          1
 ....
```

As of now I am wrote this in my controller and it's working, but I dont think it's a good solution 
since the status and users could be added and It would be hard to make new entry very often like this

**Controller**

```
if(Auth()->user()->name == 'admin'){
    $details = UserDetatils::all();
}elseif(Auth()->user()->name == 'manager'){
    $details = UserDetatils::where('status_id','1')->get();
}elseif(Auth()->user()->name == 'employee'){
    $details = UserDetatils::where('status_id','2')->get();
}...
return $details;
```

If I am following the above step, I have to create 28 elseif statements!!

Please suggest me a better option or workaround.

*`Note`*
I use Spatie package for role and pemission and laravel 6 framework

My apologies if my presentation is not clear, please dont be hesitent to shoot questions.

Comment: use middleware and seperate your controllers by role

Comment: any guides on this, please

Comment: If you are already using the spatie package, do it that way. [Here](https://freek.dev/270-a-package-to-add-roles-and-permissions-to-laravel) you have a link to the documentation, and you can search for a tutorial if you are not sure how to propose its use, [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html) is one for example

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look :)